# ionic 2 installation requirements

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic2

Am just getting started with ionic 2 and am having problems with the installation . I want to know the requirements for installing ionic 2 apart from node and npm.
Do i need to have android sdk installed? What other stuff should I have.

Comment: better to ask at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: [installation guide](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/setup/installation/)

Comment: your question is really general do the steps in installation guide. ask your problem with the error you got.

Comment: installation guide: http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-2-installation-guide/

Answer (score 0):

You would need java sdk 1.7 or higher.

You do need to download the Android Studio and install the required android sdk version for which you would want to build.

You would also need the node version of minimum of v6.9.0 or higher.
try running node --version

And do read up on ionic appscripts in github. There are changes perhaps you would need to apply - https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts

You could also Try installing nvm - 
https://github.com/creationix/nvm

its called the node version manager. will allow you to have multiple versions of node installed and certainly recommended.

Preferably try and build on the linux platform, to avoid silly issues in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Things you need for installing ionic with windows

1. nodejs
2. android sdk
3. java sdk.
4. setting path is most important
5. apache ant

   You could check out this link for installing and running to android device
   http://www.tiagoporto.com/blog/environment-setting-tutorial-ionic-android-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

to setup ionic you need to do the following
run

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

then

```
sudo npm install -g ionic
```

Done run `ionic serve` inside app folder created using 
`ionic start todo super --type v2` !!

this will help you to run app on browser
now to install on device,
you need android SDK,
and then you will be able to install apk on phone.

to do that you need to setup android SDK

use the following lines to do that

## Install openjdk

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
```

## Download android sdk

```
wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.2-linux.tgz
tar -xvf android-sdk_r24.2-linux.tgz
```

## install all sdk packages

```
cd android-sdk-linux/tools
./android update sdk --no-ui
```

## Set android-sdk path

```
pico ~/.bashrc
```

## Add these lines on top, save, and exit

```
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

## Reload bashrc

```
source ~/.bashrc
```